# How frequently do you navigate from symbol to symbol using the f + <symbol> + ' command in Vim or Neovim?

Tags: vim, neovim

Vim, as well as Neovim, allows you to navigate using specific symbols.

1. How often do you use this approach? For example, to move to the character 'g', you can press `fg'`, and to move to the next `g`, just press `'`.
2. Is this considered the fastest and default way to navigate? Or is there a better way?
3. Is it faster than using the mouse?

Comment: This question has "opinion-based" written all over it: *"how frequently do you...?" "how often do you...?" "is there a a better way?" "is it faster?"*. None of these can be answered objectively. It's a tool, it serves a specific purpose. Use the right tool for the job. And finally: just try it out and see if it helps you to become more productive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- It is `fg`, not `fg'`, and you use `;` to jump to next `g`.
- `fFtT` jump to a character, not a "symbol".

Now…

1. Very rarely. Because, precisely, I tend to jump to actual *symbols* (names, keywords, operators, etc.). I rarely operate at such a granularity level.
2. It certainly is the fastest way to jump to the next `g`. For other scenarios there are other methods. See `:help motion.txt`.
3. Using a pointing device like a mouse or trackpad works in two steps. First, the user moves the visual pointer to the target. Second, the user interacts with the target. The latter is obviously quick and easy, but the former is actually a sequence of discrete steps that are very fuzzy by nature: move in the general direction of the target, adjust your aim and move again, etc. The worst is that the farther the target the slower it gets.

   Other navigation methods, like `f<char>` and many of those documented in the help section mentioned above, can be more deterministic and therefore more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

1. use `tTfF` very often, not only for navigation, but also for editing. E.g.,  change text until next 'g': `ctg`. `;` and `,` can bring you to the next occurrence, depending on the direction.
2. I use easymotion plugin too. It breaks the line limitation of `tTfF` commands. It makes my cursor follow my focus pretty fast.
3. Much faster than mouse pointer